# Can I programmatically get at all Import/Export Specs in MS Access 2010?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am working reverse engineering an MS Access 2010 database in order to recreate it as an SSIS/SSRS solution. There a bunch of import and export specifications that I would like to document without resorting to a bunch of screen shots.

With the assistance of this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/thirdoffive/2006/10/12/the-new-importexport-specification-om/) I was able to get some XML for some of the imports and exports.

Unfortunately, I am only getting the imports and exports (eight of them) found when clicking on External Data > Saved Imports...

[image]

I have another 26 import specs that I can get to when I click on the **Advanced** button from within the Import Text Wizard dialog box and then the **Specs** button in the Import Specification dialog box.

[image]

How can get XML for the specs embedded in the Import Text Wizard like I can for those under Saved Imports? Can I transfer them to Saved Imports somehow? Or is my only option to load each spec within the Import Text Wizard and take a screen shot of it?

Thanks,

Noel

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These Import/Export specifications are stored in two system tables: `MSysIMEXSpecs` and `MSysIMEXColumns`.

To display them:

- Right-click on the header in the navigation pane and choose `Navigation Options...`
- In the `Navigation Options` window check the `Show System Objects` box and click Ok

(courtesy of https://superuser.com/questions/268077/how-do-i-view-system-tables-for-a-mdb-in-access-2010)

Or create a query like this:

```
SELECT MSysIMEXSpecs.SpecName, MSysIMEXColumns.*
FROM MSysIMEXColumns INNER JOIN MSysIMEXSpecs 
     ON MSysIMEXColumns.SpecID = MSysIMEXSpecs.SpecID
```

Comment: I would really like to know why the same type of thing is stored in different places.

Comment: @nscheaffer - Two words: "Backward compatibility". The newer "Saved Imports/Exports" mechanism was added after the older "MSysIMEX..." method had already been around for *many* years. During that time *lots* of code was written to use `DoCmd.TransferText` et. al. that relied on the older way of storing the import/export specifications.