# Get Mappings From Linked Table To Use In VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013, linked-tables

I have a `.txt` file that is being used as a linked table in Access 2010.  The file has no delimiter and has custom mappings added to where each field starts/ends.  Is there a way for me to "pull out" the mappings from that linked table that is already perfectly set up and mapped in order to use this for a `VBA` procedure?

Comment: The data you are looking for may be the Import/Export specifications, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36224726/3820271

Comment: @Andre - looking at the MSysIMEXColumns I have over 829 rows in this table.  How do I determine which rows go with which linked table?

Comment: With the link (via `SpecID`) to `MSysIMEXSpecs`. But if nothing there resembles your linked table, I'm wrong and this data isn't what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to the Access database then you can query the linked table using SQL. If not then there's not way to benefit from the existing mapping in Access.