# Save a query as text tab delimited but include ".ail2" in the saved name. (ACCESS)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to export a query as a text file from an access database but using vba. The issue is I need to save it with .ail2 in the name.

basically I want it of the form: **"currentdate_version.ail2".txt** (the quotations are very important otherwise it won't work).

So for example todays first version would look like:

**"20182910_1.ail2".txt**

I have tried exporting it manually and saving it as this but the export wizard doesn't seem to like the quotation marks in the saved name. I have therefore been exporting it (using a custom saved export that i've labelled test1 - it includes the headers of each column, sets the text qualifier as 'none', the field delimiter as 'tab' and file format is 'delimited').

I am using the following code in access, the first part just makes sure the folder with the current date exists.

```
Private Sub ExportExcel()


    Dim myQueryName As String
    Dim myExportFileName As String
    Dim strSheets As String
    Dim sFolderPath As String
    Dim filename As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    strSheets = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")

    sFolderPath = "M:\AIL2Files\" & strSheets & ""

    Dim fdObj As Object

    Set fdObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fdObj.FolderExists("" & sFolderPath & "") Then
    Else
        fdObj.CreateFolder ("" & sFolderPath & "")
    End If
    i = 1
    filename = Dir(sFolderPath & "\*" & i & ".txt")

    Do While Len(filename) > 0
    filename = Dir(sFolderPath & "\*" & i & ".txt")
    i = i + 1
    Loop


    myQueryName = "001_querytest"
    myExportFileName = "" & sFolderPath & "\" & Chr(34) & "" & strSheets & "_" & i & ".ail2" & Chr(34) & ".txt"
    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "test1", myQueryName, myExportFileName, True




End Sub
```

**test1** isn't being picked up even though its a 'saved export'. I assume I'm doing this part wrong... but even still I reckon the save won't be successful and will not include the quotation marks.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I have tried doing the following instead:

```
DoCmd.TransferText transferType:=acExportDelim, TableName:=myQueryName, filename:=myExportFileName, hasfieldnames:=True
```

It now saves, but again not including the quotation marks as desired. Whats interesting is when I type `?myExportFileName` in the immediate window, it displays my desired filename but the command is clearly not working correctly as I get it of the form:

```
_20181029_1#ail2_
```

Instead...

**Here is image if I use save as:**
[image: Savetext]

**I end up getting:**
[image: Result]

Comment: File names can't contain quotes (see list of [reserved characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words)). If the quotes are really important, I think you should redesign your code not to make them necessary.

Comment: I figured this would be the case... I'm afraid its not possible though the .ail2 file is used by a different bit of software and it works if I go to 'Save As' on the text  file and save it with the quotations... it works and I get my ail2 file...

Comment: I really don't see which other software might be using a file name containing quotes, since quotes are forbidden by the operating system. I'm sorry to tell you will never manage to save a file using quotes in the name (neither in VBA, nor manually, nor anyhow else as the OS will reject you). If the bit of code wanting quotes is yours, I highly suggest to change it.

Comment: It converts the file into an .ail2 file by including the quotes. The problem is if I don't follow this method the format is destroyed and won't be read correctly by the other software. See my picture above...

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I wish I could, as I agree its a flawed method. Is there a way to save a file as a custom filetype? ie save as .ail2 directly... I'd be interested to try something like this out to see if it still works...

Comment: Of course, you can directly save it as .ail2. That's actually what you should be doing if .ail2 is the expected extension of your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround to this is first saving the file as a .txt using `DoCmd.TransferText`, but running a shell and renaming. Like such:

```
myExportFileName = sFolderPath & "\" & strSheets & "_" & i & ".txt"



DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acExportDelim, SpecificationName:="034_AILFILE Export Specification", TableName:=myQueryName, filename:=myExportFileName, HasFieldnames:=True

Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strDocuments = wshShell.SpecialFolders("M:\AIL2Files\" & strSheets & "")
oldFileName = myExportFileName
newFileName = sFolderPath & "\" & strSheets & "_" & i & ".ail2"

Name oldFileName As newFileName
```

There is undoubtedly cleaner ways of doing this but I imagine that this method could be used to save any files that have non traditional extensions, but fundamentally follow the format of a .txt file.

Comment: It is actually quite possible that `DoCmd.TransferText` refuses to save as `.ail2`, it may have a fixed set of allowed extensions like .txt and .csv. So your approach to export as .txt and rename as .ail2 is a reasonable workaround, I would do the same.

Answer (score 1):

There are some misconceptions here.

Windows file names cannot contain double quotes `"`, period. And you don't need them, either. Just save your file as `filename.ail2`.

This is what you get when doing "Save as". [Tell Explorer to show file extensions](https://www.howtogeek.com/205086/beginner-how-to-make-windows-show-file-extensions/), and you'll see that you don't have `"filename.ail2".txt` but `filename.ail2`.

You only need

```
myExportFileName = sFolderPath & "\" & strSheets & "_" & i & ".ail2"
```

---

> **test1** isn't being picked up even though its a 'saved export'.

`DoCmd.TransferText` doesn't use saved exports, but export specifications. See here for the difference:
[Can I programmatically get at all Import/Export Specs in MS Access 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222661/can-i-programmatically-get-at-all-import-export-specs-in-ms-access-2010)

#### Addendum

`DoCmd.TransferText` could throw a runtime error when given an illegal file name, but apparently it tries to save the day by exchanging the illegal characters by `_`, hence `_20181029_1#ail2_ (.txt)`

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have incorporated the export specification using the method you have suggested. I now get a 'Run-time error '3027'' - Cannot Update. Database or object is read-only. And upon debug it highlights what I've ammended to be:  `DoCmd.TransferText transferType:=acExportDelim, SpecificationName:="034_AILFILE Export Specification", TableName:=myQueryName, filename:=myExportFileName, hasfieldnames:=True` . I have selected the database to 'never cache' but I still get this error...

Comment: The error seems to be happening when i try and save as .ail2 file directly... If i save as ail2.txt it does the export, but as a txt file obviously... I am struggling to see how one can save as a .ail2 file directly...