How do I copy Import/Export Specifications from one database to another?
I've run into a corruption issue with my Access database where I can no longer compact/repair or change the password.  From doing a bit of research, the fix is to just scrap the existing file and migrate the contents over to a new file.  I've got a function set up to take care of moving all Access Objects over, however there is a single Import/Export Specification utilized by one of my scripts that I'm unable to figure out how to migrate via VBA.  Is there a way to move the Import/Export Specifications over other than hand-jamming it, or is there a better way I should be saving and referencing these should I need to salvage my database again in the future?

If it is about the old specification type, used in DoCmd.TransferText, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222661/can-i-programmatically-get-at-all-import-export-specs-in-ms-access-2010

Had no idea the import spec was hiding in that system table.  This is what I was hunting for.

You can use CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications to work with import/export specifications. They are stored as XML.
The pseudocode is something like this:
For the corrupted database, assuming it can still run code:
Dim imexspec As Object
For Each imexspec In CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications
    ' Do not actually print but write to a place where the other database can access it
    Debug.Print imexspec.Name; imexspec.XML
End For

And for the new database:
'Obtain array of names and array of XMLs somehow
For i = LBound(NameArray) To UBound(NameArray)
    CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.Add NameArray(i), XMLArray(i)
Next

